# Formation of methane using Kolbe's electrolysis reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

I have read in my book that methane cannot be formed using Kolbe's reaction ([mechanism — Organic Chemistry Portal](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/kolbe-electrolysis.shtm)). And honestly, I kinda think I get where they are coming from: that *two radicals are required to get a hydrocarbon which can in the least be two methyl radicals* (of course when substrate is sodium acetate) which can combine to give ethane.

Why can't we use a mixture of sodium formate and sodium acetate and expect *some* methane to be released? Why shouldn't it work?

Comment: If you notice the actual mechanism that you have provided, you would notice that R-H is formed albeit in a very small amount.

Comment: Even though it deals with Wurtz reaction, tempted to call a dupe of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65303/why-can-wurtz-reaction-be-not-used-for-preparation-of-alkanes-with-odd-number-of